# Boost library error

Tags: c++, boost

Trying to install boost libraries ...

Error : The system cannot find the path specified. Access is denied.

I have installed MinGw and in User/AppData folder and added to path as I don't have admin privileges on this machine. Both work. My guess is either bootstrap.bat can't find gcc or it's trying to write to a place like c:\boost\ where it doesn't have permission to do so.

I have also extracted boost in AppData folder for same permission rules.

I tried

```
>bootstrap.bat prefix=[Appdata full path]
```

still getting same error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

So I built Boost on my personal machine on which I have admin privileges. Then I transfered the build output to AppData on machine on which I don't have admin privs. Everything works beautiful now.